# convert sql statement to linq;

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC 3 application.
I write with entity framework and linq
but I have a question on the linq statement

1. if you have:

   ```
   select a, (select d from tabled where id = '12 ') as c from tableA inner join TableB on tablea.id = tableb.id
   ```

   then switch to linq how (using the controller and assign with ViewBag.str = ...)
   (how can the view, you can display a and c)
2. and if his statement is, for example: `Product product = db.Product.Find (id)`
   then how do you determine if product is empty or not?

Answer (score 0):

var a= from p in tableA join q in tableB on p.id equals q.id select new {p.a, from r in tabled where r.id == 12 select r.d}.ToList();

this is the LINQ query for the statement. Also

you can use

```
Product product = db.Product.Find (id);
if (product == null) return "Emplty";
```

Comment: is this working for u... pls make it as answer if it helps u.

Comment: thank you
and if I pass it to 1 ViewBag.str = from p in tableA join q in TableB on p.id equals q.id select new {pa, from r print tabled where r.id == 12 select rd}. ToList ();
how you can separate each field (pa, rd) is from this ViewBag.str!

Comment: no its not possible to add to view bag instead of u can return this query result through the return view(ans); then u cn easily take the properties inside the view

Comment: thank you
So how we will use it
return view (str)
right now, str is an array?
str ['a'] is not
and if you want to use multiple queries
var str1 = from p in tableA join q in TableB on p.id equals q.id select new {pa, from r print tabled where r.id == 12 select rd}. ToList ();
var str2 = from p in tableA join q in TableB on p.id equals q.id select new {pa, from r print tabled where r.id == 12 select rd}. ToList ();
So to return the view like?

Answer (score 0):

you have to follo the following steps;
1) create the return value class in the model as :

```
public class ClassResult
{
    public int a1 { get; set; }
    public int b1 { get; set; }
}
```

then on the controller

write the query as follows:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<TableAClass> ListA = new List<TableAClass>();
        List<TableBClass> ListB = new List<TableBClass>();
        List<TableCClass> ListC = new List<TableCClass>();

        List<ClassResult> res = new List<ClassResult>();

        res = (from p1 in ListA join p2 in ListB on p1.a1 equals p2.b1 select new ClassResult { a1=p1.a1 ,b1=p2.b1 }).ToList();

        return View(res);
    }
```

3) on the view,

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.ClassResult>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Index1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="display-label">a1</div>
        <div class="display-field"><%: Model.a1 %></div>

        <div class="display-label">b1</div>
        <div class="display-field"><%: Model.b1 %></div>

    </fieldset>


</body>
</html>
```